# Создание инфоблоков в bitrix

Tags: битрикс, php

Добрый день.

Подскажите, как создавать инфоблоки в bitrix?
На оф. сайте был - не понял. Есть страница site.com/production/product654.html
Нужно, чтобы работал роутинг, товар "product654" обрабатывался и выводилась по нём информация.

Как такое сделать?
Спасибо.

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Если вы НЕ хотите лезть в код, то можете все сделать визуально:

1. Создать инфоблок "Товары" с необходимыми свойствами. Создать необходимое кол-во товаров товаров.
2. Создать страницу, на которой будет отображаться выбранный товар. Как создавать страницы, читайте тут: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=34&LESSON_ID=1911
3. На странице разместить компонент просмотра детальной новости, называется news.detail. Там укажете параметр ELEMENT_ID, это id вашего товара. В настройках укажите выборку с ранее созданного инфоблока "ТОВАРЫ". Например у вас товар 654, значит ссылка будет в виде site.ru/product/detail.php?ELEMENT_ID=654
4. Готово!

Если вы хотите сделать красивую ссылку, типа ../product654, то Вам нужно настроить перенаправление. Это делается при помощи urlrewrite.

Answer (score 1):

В настройках инфоблока прописать пути SEF

Для вашего случая
/production/product#ELEMENT_ID#.html